# Is there a way to make the Y-axis not adapt to the loaded tables for Google Column Charts?

Tags: php, html, sql, charts, visualization

I'm currently committing to an information security project where fictional data is loaded and visualized with google charts. However, with the column chart that's being loaded, the Y-axis is loaded in an unwanted manner, and **i've tried multiple tests to identify where the issue is, but so far no luck**.

I have 3 Tables, with 2 attributes each. These tables are: 'Phishing', 'SpearPhishing', and 'RogueRouter'. They all have two columns that i want to count and present with the attribute names such as 'curious' and 'intent'.

**The following SQL syntax is being used:**

```
SELECT 'Phishing' as method, count(check_opened) as curious, count(clicked_link)
as intent FROM Phishing UNION ALL SELECT 'Spear Phishing' as method, count(check_opened)
as curious, count(clicked_link) as intent FROM SpearPhishing UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Rogue Router' as method, count(page_load) as curious, count(internet_intent)
as intent FROM RogueRouter GROUP BY method
```

**In Phpmyadmin, when run, it displays the following:**

[image]

**However, with the following code in my PHP file to display the data as columns:**

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "isprojectdbadmin", "isproject!23", "ISProjectDB");  
 $query = [THE SQL QUERY MENTIONED ABOVE]
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 ?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['method', 'curious', 'intent'],

         <?php
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
             echo "['".$row['method']."', '".$row['curious']."', '".$row['intent']."'], ";
          }
         ?>

        ]);
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**It displays the following:**

[image]

The Y-axis isn't gradient in its values where it initiates from 0 to 40, and **i have no idea** where the issue resides. Any help is greatly appreciated, or even some slight recommendations would be beneficial since i'm feeling a bit stuck. In addition, as i've mentioned in the beginning of this post, there's no malicious activities behind this project what so ever, quite the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by my self! The issue was the PHP syntax for reading the rows.

The following row:

```
echo "['".$row['method']."', '".$row['curious']."', '".$row['intent']."'], ";
```

was replaced by:

```
echo "['".$row["method"]."', ".$row["curious"].", ".$row["intent"].", ],";
```